# CriteriaBuilder.isEmpty on an ElementCollection vs. JPQL approach

Tags: api, jpa, criteria, eclipselink

I'm trying to do a simple query using the JPA2 criteria API on the following class(es):

```
// a lot of imports

@Entity
public class Thing {
    enum Type { FIRST, SECOND, THIRD };

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "Thing_SeqGen", sequenceName = "Thing_Id_Seq", initialValue = 1000)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "Thing_SeqGen")
    private int id;

    private String name = "name";

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Thing.Type.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "TYPES", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "ID", name = "TYPE_ID") })

    private Set<Thing.Type> typeSet = new HashSet<Thing.Type>();
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Thing().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        final Thing firstThing = new Thing();
        firstThing.setName("First one");
        firstThing.setTypeSet(EnumSet.of(Thing.Type.FIRST));
        final Thing firstAndSecondThing = new Thing();
        firstAndSecondThing.setName("Test2");
        firstAndSecondThing.setTypeSet(EnumSet.of(Thing.Type.FIRST, Thing.Type.SECOND));
        final Thing bareThing = new Thing();
        bareThing.setName("Test3");

        final EntityManagerFactory emf =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sandbox");
        final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(firstThing);
        em.persist(firstAndSecondThing);
        em.persist(bareThing);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<Thing> c = cb.createQuery(Thing.class);
        final Root<Thing> root = c.from(Thing.class);
        final Join<Thing, Set<Thing.Type>> typeJoin = root.join("typeSet");

        c.select(root).distinct(true).where(cb.isEmpty(typeJoin));

        final List<Thing> results = em.createQuery(c).getResultList();

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    // getter/setter methods omitted
}
```

What I want to query: Find all things which has no typeset.

The JPQL which does the job is:

`select t from Thing t where t.typeSet is empty`

The JPQL query returns one result which is expected. The criteria query returns no results. The `CriteriaBuilder` created:

`SELECT DISTINCT t0.ID, t0.NAME FROM THING t0, TYPES t1 WHERE (((SELECT COUNT(t2.ID) FROM THING t2 WHERE (t1.TYPE_ID = t0.ID)) = 0) **AND (t1.TYPE_ID = t0.ID)**)`

The last theta-join (marked **) kills it all. And I have no idea why the table `THING` is specified twice `(THING to, THING t1)`.

Obviously I'm doing wrong. But I have no clue what's the fault.

Comment: It would be normal on Stackoverflow to mark an answer if it answered your question, and if not to say that you tried it without success etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess the problem is that you're trying to do an explicit join in the Criteria case, whereas in the JPQL you don't. So omit the join and do something like

```
Metamodel model = emf.getMetamodel();
ManagedType thingType = model.managedType(Thing.class);
CollectionAttribute typeSetAttr = thingType.getCollection("typeSet");
c.select(root).distinct(true).where(cb.isEmpty(root.get(typeSetAttr)));
```

This should then translate into the same JPQL as you posted ... or at least it does for DataNucleus JPA implementation.