# How do I say in JPA, give me all objects whose Collection field has at least one item in another list?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, jpa-2.1

I have JPA entity with the following field:

```java
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_organization", 
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") },  
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ORGANIZATION_ID") })
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@SortNatural
private SortedSet<Organization> organizations = new TreeSet<Organization>();
```

Given a list of `Organization` objects (myOrgs) and using CriteriaBuilder, how do I write a clause to say:

> Give me all the `User` objects who have at least one `Organization` in the
>   `myOrgs` variable ?

I tried the following but without success...

```java
final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
final Root<User> userRoot = criteria.from(User.class);
criteria.where(builder.isMember(myOrgs, userRoot.get(User_.organizations)), ...
```

I’m using JPA 2.1 with Hibernate 4.3.6.Final.

Comment: Helpful URL ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340554/criteriabuilder-isempty-on-an-elementcollection-vs-jpql-approach

Comment: Have you tried with SQL / JPQL first ? Translation to criteria would be much easier then.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, I would try the following:

```
//GET A LIST OF IDS
List<Long> orgsIds = new ArrayList<>();
for (Organization org : myOrgs){
    orgsIds.add(org.getId());
}

//CREATE QUERY WITH JOIN AND NOT FINAL
CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> userRoot = criteria.from(User.class);
Join<User,Organization> organizationJoin = userRoot.join(User_.organizations,JoinType.INNER)

//DISTINCT BECAUSE JOIN WITH MULTIPLE ORGs RETURN REPEATED RESULTS
criteria.select(cb.distinct(userRoot));

criteria.where(organizationJoin.get(Organization_.id).in(orgsIds));
```

Another option, new in JPA 2.1 and more eficient is in the join add another condition like this:

```
Join<User,Organization> organizationJoin = userRoot.join(User_.organizations,JoinType.INNER);
organizationJoin.on(cb.and(organizationJoin.get(Organization_.id).in(orgsIds)));
```

and removing where clause